trying to read GeoJson File but I get this error message CPLE_OpenFailedError
I'm trying to read a GeoJson file: acs2022_5yr_B01003_15000US060371198021.geojson
I downloaded the following libraries:
to read and visualize spatial data
import geopandas as gpd
to provide basemaps
import contextily as ctx
to give more power to your figures (plots)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
I saved the geojson in my folder (see path below): OneDrive/pscript/Practice_1/data/acs2022_5yr_B01003_15000US060371198021.geojson
Then I enter the following:
gdf = gpd.read_file('OneDrive/pscript/Practice_1/data/acs2022_5yr_B01003_15000US060371198021.geojson')
I get the following message: What does this mean?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
File fiona\\ogrext.pyx:136, in fiona.ogrext.gdal_open_vector()

File fiona\\_err.pyx:291, in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: OneDrive/pscript/Practice_1/data/acs2022_5yr_B01003_15000US060371198021.geojson: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DriverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 # load a data file
      2 # note the relative filepath! where is this file located?
----> 3 gdf = gpd.read_file('OneDrive/pscript/Practice_1/data/acs2022_5yr_B01003_15000US060371198021.geojson')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:297, in _read_file(filename, bbox, mask, rows, engine, **kwargs)
    294     else:
    295         path_or_bytes = filename
--> 297     return _read_file_fiona(
    298         path_or_bytes, from_bytes, bbox=bbox, mask=mask, rows=rows, **kwargs
    299     )
    301 else:
    302     raise ValueError(f"unknown engine '{engine}'")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:338, in _read_file_fiona(path_or_bytes, from_bytes, bbox, mask, rows, where, **kwargs)
    335     reader = fiona.open
    337 with fiona_env():
--> 338     with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
    339         crs = features.crs_wkt
    340         # attempt to get EPSG code

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py:457, in ensure_env_with_credentials.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwds)
    454     session = DummySession()
    456 with env_ctor(session=session):
--> 457     return f(*args, **kwds)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py:292, in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, allow_unsupported_drivers, **kwargs)
    289     path = parse_path(fp)
    291 if mode in ("a", "r"):
--> 292     colxn = Collection(
    293         path,
    294         mode,
    295         driver=driver,
    296         encoding=encoding,
    297         layer=layer,
    298         enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers,
    299         allow_unsupported_drivers=allow_unsupported_drivers,
    300         **kwargs
    301     )
    302 elif mode == "w":
    303     colxn = Collection(
    304         path,
    305         mode,
   (...)
    314         **kwargs
    315     )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py:243, in Collection.__init__(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, include_fields, wkt_version, allow_unsupported_drivers, **kwargs)
    241 if self.mode == "r":
    242     self.session = Session()
--> 243     self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
    244 elif self.mode in ("a", "w"):
    245     self.session = WritingSession()

File fiona\\ogrext.pyx:588, in fiona.ogrext.Session.start()

File fiona\\ogrext.pyx:143, in fiona.ogrext.gdal_open_vector()

DriverError: OneDrive/pscript/Practice_1/data/acs2022_5yr_B01003_15000US060371198021.geojson: No such file or directory


As the error states: the file is not being found on the location you specify:
DriverError: OneDrive/pscript/Practice_1/data/acs2022_5yr_B01003_15000US060371198021.geojson:
No such file or directory

Note that you are using a relative path as it doesn't start with /. So the file will be searched starting from the "current directory" you are running it, which isn't always super transparent where that is. Best make it an absolute path.

You're welcome. If it solves your issue, best mark it as "Answered" so it is clear for everyone that it is not necessary anymore to look into it.
